# What HTML tags are invalid in the body of an HTML page?

Tags: html

Recently in using a content management system I had an experience where a content editor inserted the `<title>` tag into an article's body. This caused the page to behave weirdly  because that's not legitimate HTML. The content editor is highly trusted and needs access to a long list of HTML tags so they can insert and style images, embed videos or other 3rd party widgets.

I'm adjusting the site to limit which HTML tags they are allowed to use and can't find a list of tags that should just never occur in the body of a page. I was surprised I couldn't find a list, so I figured I'd ask here.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this list is exhaustive, but a little research shows that for various reasons, these don't belong in the < Body > section:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
<title>
<body>
<meta>
<link>
<base>
```

Comment: Based on this article it looks like you can use the <meta> and <link> tags in the <body> section if the itemprop attribute is present. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content